# What is the data type of (1) in python?

Tags: python

```
a = (1)
b = ('y')
```

The output of `type(a)` is `int`, isn't it supposed to be a `tuple`? Similarly, `type(b)` is `str`.

How does this make it an `int` or `str` or `float` etc for the single value inside the round brackets?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do not have the correct syntax of a one-element tuple:

```
type((1)) # int
type((1,)) # tuple
```